# Concatenating multiple data frames in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm reading a pdf with multiple pages. The tables on each page have the exact same format. The resulting data frames come out as expected ([X rows x 10 cols]), except there are a few that come out with dimensions of [X rows x 11 cols] for some unknown reason. When I concatenate these data frames to create one large data frame, the combined data frame ends up with the expected number of rows, but the resulting number of columns is 16.

To create the combined data frame, I did the following:

```
df = tabula.read_pdf(file/path, pages = 'all')
combined_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(df)):
    combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, df[i]])
```

This created a data frame with the correct rows and but added columns resulting in a data frame with dimensions [X rows x 16 cols].

I tried adding .reset_index() like so:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, df[i].reset_index()])
```

I also tried:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, df[i]], ignore_index = True)
```

The above attempts gave the same unexpected columns. Then I tried adding a While loop and an IF statement to make sure that the rows and columns of each data frame were the same dimensions before concatenating.

```
j = 0
    while j <= (len(df) - 1)
        shape = df[j].shape
        if shape[1] > expected_cols
            df[j] = df[j].drop(df[j].columns[-1], axis = 1)
        j += 1
```

This also did not change anything. Through close investigation, the problem occurs when concatenating the data frames that have 11 columns. When I just tried to concatenate two data frames, one that I know has the correct number of columns and one that I know has 11 columns I will get a resulting data frame with 16 columns. My best guess is that these two data frames have column names that are slightly different (bc of the extra column) and this is causing some issue.

Comment: Can you provide a (minimal) example of two data frames for reproducing the error?

Comment: This is how [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) behaves. It combines common and unique columns when generating the full frame. Any slight change to name will be considered unique.